# Roslyn detect ternary operator like ? :

Tags: c#, roslyn, ternary-operator

I have been looking for a solution, which let find the ternary operators like `true ? DoIt() : DoItNot();` with the roslyn analyzer library.

I came up with following solution, but this returns only the "standard" if-else-Expressions.

```
var ifStatement = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<IfStatementSyntax>().First();
```

I did search for another `SyntaxKind`, but I didn´t find what I am looking for.
So I would be very pleased if someone has a solution for my problem.

Comment: Have you tested LINQPad, where you can inspect the syntax tree of the code you input?

Comment: Not yet, thank you for this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`SyntaxKind.ConditionalExpression`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxKind.cs#L308).

Answer (score 1):

```
tree.GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Where(node => node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ConditionalExpression))
```